# Sort out some entries from result of a query

Tags: sql-server-2008, sorting

I can not explain what exactly I want in words that's why I prefer to show a small example.

I am using SQL Server, and have this table:

```
col1    |   col2   | col3
--------+----------+------------
john    | conner   | 01.01.1980
sarah   | conner   | 03.04.1978
john    | conner   | 01.01.1977
```

I have a table with 3 entries (for example) with 2 of them are almost the same with a different in the col3.

How can I delete the entry with the smallst col3 (which is 01.01.1980) and keep the one with 01.01.1977, so I get this table as final result

```
col1    |   col2   | col3
--------+----------+------------
sarah   | conner   | 03.04.1978
john    | conner   | 01.01.1977
```

So simply is my question : how can I compare entries in the same table and take the entries that are almost the same but with a different in the col3 which is the Age and I want to take the older John Conner ...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CREATE TABLE TabStack
(
    col1 varchar(10),
    col2 varchar(10),
    col3 date
)

insert into TabStack
values(

'john','conner','01.01.1980'),
('sarah','conner','03.04.1978'),
('john','conner','01.01.1977')

with cte
as
(
select col1, col2, col3, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by col1,col2 order by col3) rn
from TabStack
)

delete from cte
where rn>1

--select * from TabStack

Answer (score 0):

A simple `GROUP BY` query should work:

```
SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    MIN(CONVERT(datetime, col3, 104)) AS col3
    -- or just MIN(col3) AS col3
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    col1,
    col2
```

I'm not sure if you stored your dates as text or as actual dates.  If the former, then you can use `CONVERT()` to bring them to datetime before using `MIN()`.  If the latter, then just use `MIN(col3)` to get the earlier dates.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

**Update:**

Here is a general query which will return the entire max record per group, along with ties:

```
SELECT
    t.col1, t.col2, t.col3, t.col4, ...
FROM
(
    SELECT t.*,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col3) dr
    FROM yourTable t
) t
WHERE t.dr = 1;
```

If you don't want ties, then replace `DENSE_RANK` with `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: That is almost what i am looking for. But what if there is another Column with alos different data in it what is not important for me but i want it to be showed in the final result table. Like i have two entries with same Data in col1 and col2 and different Value ( Ages) in Col3 and also different Value in Col4. When the Data in Col1 and Col2 are the same then I compare the data in col3 and take Min or Max and I do not care what the value in Col4 is but i need it in the finale result table. I guess the GROUP BY Methode would not work in this case right ?

Comment: Well let us know what the problem is and maybe we can update the answer.

Comment: Done and thank you again. The RANK princip is that what I needed.